# service won't autostart on boot

Tags: services, autostart

So I have been trying to autostart a service and I'm getting no where. I've tried autobooting on both Mint 19.3 and 20 and Ubuntu 18.04 for the service `lizardfs-chunkserver.service` and autostarting the service does not work.

The way that I autostart a service is with the command:

```
systemctl enable lizardfs-chunkserver.service
```

Originally I thought it was a OS issue but when I try to auto start a different service,

```
systemctl enable lizardfs-master.service
```

The `lizardfs-master` service auto started fine.

This leads me to believe that I'm unable to autostart `lizardfs-chunkserver` because something to do with the service itself.

Below are a few things that I've found but I haven't been able to get any further. As a side note, I am able to start `lizardfs-chunkserver`with `systemctl start lizardfs-chunkserver` manually.

1. From `systemctl status lizardfs-chunkserver.service` I see the error:

```
● lizardfs-chunkserver.service - LizardFS chunkserver daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lizardfs-chunkserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-10-16 22:34:39 PDT; 11h ago
       Docs: man:mfschunkserver
    Process: 856 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mfschunkserver start (code=exited, status=2)

Oct 16 22:34:39 13in-dell systemd[1]: lizardfs-chunkserver.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Oct 16 22:34:39 13in-dell mfschunkserver[863]: hdd space manager: folder /mnt/hd1/ will be scanned
Oct 16 22:34:39 13in-dell systemd[1]: lizardfs-chunkserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 16 22:34:39 13in-dell mfschunkserver[863]: hdd space manager: path to scan: /mnt/hd1/
Oct 16 22:34:39 13in-dell systemd[1]: Failed to start LizardFS chunkserver daemon.
Oct 16 22:34:39 13in-dell mfschunkserver[863]: hdd space manager: start background hdd scanning (searching for available chunks)
Oct 16 22:34:39 13in-dell mfschunkserver[863]: main server module: listen on *:9422
Oct 16 22:34:39 13in-dell mfschunkserver[863]: master connection module: connect failed: Network is unreachable
Oct 16 22:34:39 13in-dell mfschunkserver[863]: init: master connection module failed
Oct 16 22:34:39 13in-dell mfschunkserver[863]: closing *:9422
```

2. From `journalctl -xe | grep lizard` I get the error:

```
Oct 16 22:34:39 13in-dell systemd[1]: lizardfs-chunkserver.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit lizardfs-chunkserver.service has exited.
Oct 16 22:34:39 13in-dell systemd[1]: lizardfs-chunkserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- The unit lizardfs-chunkserver.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
```

3. I noticed that the `lizardfs-master` must be running in order for `lizardfs-chunkserver` to start so this whole time I've ensure the `master` is up and running. I've even tried to modify the `lizardfs-chunkserver.service` file to delay the service to start by 10 seconds just in case it has something to do with unable to see the network upon restart. I've include the `/lib/systemd/system/lizardfs-chunkserver.service` content below:

```
[Unit]
Description=LizardFS chunkserver daemon
Documentation=man:mfschunkserver
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
TimeoutSec=10
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mfschunkserver start
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/mfschunkserver stop
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/mfschunkserver reload
Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Are you running both `lizardfs-master` and `lizardfs-chunkserver` on the same machine?

Comment: I have tried running them both on the same machine as well as not on the same machine.

Comment: Two absolute guesses: (1) try After=network-online.target; (2) is something else using port 9422?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I got around it by putting this in the [Service] section of my chunkserver systemd config:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5
```

This makes it wait 5 seconds before starting.

Comment: I wonder why it worked for you but not for the OP. "I've even tried to modify the lizardfs-chunkserver.service file to delay the service to start by 10 seconds just in case it has something to do with unable to see the network upon restart."

Comment: I think ExecStartPre is a bit different to TimeoutSec (which the OP was using). I'm pretty sure TimeoutSec just adjusts the amount of time that systemd is prepared to wait for a response.

I have actually had to increase this value - 5 seconds isn't always long enough. I set it to 15 just to be sure.